# Display SVG on 3D planes using openGL

Tags: opengl, svg, openvg

I have a requirement to draw different SVG files on respective 3D planes. For example, if I have two SVG files, I want to render them on two different 3D planes in openGL so that the planes can then have independent orientations in space. I tried using openVG for this purpose, but as I see, it only allows to use 2D transformations.

Is there a way to do this in openVG or some other openGL based approach?

Comment: Is it necessary to use OpenGL, or could you use [CSS 3D transforms](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/)?

Comment: OpenVG is in no way based on OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the approach of rendering SVG to a texture, then map that texture to the 3d planes that you oriented in openGL.

Alternatively, you can wrap the root SVG visual with a [perspective transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG-Transforms/#perspective-definitions) that does the equivalent 3D transform you want applied to each plane.

Comment: The SVG Transform specification you link to is being replaced by a joint svg/css specification, see http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transforms/.

Answer (score 1):

Render SVG to texture, draw textured quad in desired orientation.